# "Micro-payment Channel" on Ethereum?

Tags: contract-design, state-channels

Is there any **`payment channel`** on Ethereum blockchain to support ex. **`Micro-payments`** ? Similar to the payment channels listed here : 
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Payment_channels

Such that we are able to use these payment channels using **Smart Contracts**.

Comment: I've written a few blog posts about how to do this. https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/ is the most introductory.

Comment: @smarx Thank you for your code. In fact one of my questions is that in case we do not call `selfdestruct(sender);` (apparently to kill the contract) then what may happen ? Thanks again.

Comment: You could do `sender.transfer(address(this).balance);` instead and just leave the contract alive.

Comment: @smarx Thank you. So in this case we do not have any security (or other type of ) problems ? if we leave the contract alive ? and in case of function `claimTimeout()` is it possible to use `sender.transfer(address(this).balance);` instead of `selfdestruct(sender);` ? It seems that both does the same thing, isn't it? Thanks

Comment: No, I don't think there's any problem keeping the contract alive. Yes, you could make that change in `claimTimeout()`. Both do mostly the same thing, but using `selfdestruct` also destroys the contract and gives you a gas refund, so it saves a little of the transaction cost.

Comment: @smarx And finally we don't need to add an `address.transfer()` or `address.send()` to this contract when a channel becomes opened to transfer micro payments when channel is opened ? It seems the only `transfer` function is in `close` function when the channel becomes closed. Thanks

Comment: In the original code, funds are transferred to the recipient in `close()` and to the sender in `close()` and `claimTimeout()`. If you're getting rid of the `selfdestruct`s for some reason, you'll need to replace them both with `sender.transfer(address(this).balance);`.

Comment: Why would something need to be sent when the channel is opening? I think you may be misunderstanding the concept of a payment channel... nothing is transferred on-chain until the channel is closed. Until then, the ether is held in escrow, and off-chain payment messages are sent.

Comment: @smarx OK, so if I understood `sender.transfer(address(this).balance);` **micro** payments (that are transferred `off-chain`) to the `recipient` ? Isn't it? In fact, `address(this).balance` is the balance of sender I think, so this probably transfers the entire balance to the recipient instead of sending `off-chain micro-payments` I'm wrong ? Thanks

Comment: `address(this).balance` is the balance of the smart contract. `sender.transfer(address(this).balance);` sends the entire balance of the smart contract to the sender.

Comment: @smarx Sorry for typo :  I mean `address(this).balance` is the balance of **channel** I think.

Comment: @smarx Thank you again. For avoiding several questions :-) if you could grant me an example of how to use your code (in particular JavaScript) everything will be clear to me. For an example, assuming `payer` wants to pay `recipient` `1 ETH` in general and in `10 times` (`10 * 0.1 ETH`) and assuming we've deployed contract and its address is ex, `0x123`. In fact, I'm looking for sequence of invoking functions (JavaScript and Solidity). Thank you very much

Comment: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/17/signing-and-verifying-messages-in-ethereum/ shows how to sign messages in JavaScript. The sender would send a message to the recipient with 0.1 ether and then 0.2 ether, etc., with a last message of 1 ether. Then the recipient would pass that message to `close()`.

Comment: @smarx Thank you, the only thing is not yet clear to me is that at the time of deploying contract and contract constructor (i.e. `SimplePaymentChannel`) `sender` does not need to determine the total amount that `recipient` must  receive at the time of closing the channel ? (in my above example ex, `1 ETH`)  as balance of channel ? Thanks again

Comment: The amount `recipient` gets when the channel closed is the amount that was in the signed message they presented. The rest goes back to the `sender`.

Comment: @smarx Thanks, Yes, Of course, For example, consider the **total** amount that `recipient` will be received (i.e. the channel balance) is `1 ETH`. Then in first signed message, `payer` pays `0.1 ETH` and in second signed message `0.2 ETH`. At this point, `recipient` decides to close channel. Then, the rest (i.e. `0.8 ETH`) goes back to the `sender`. However, I mean **where** in the `Solidity code` (in which `function`) we initiate and determine this total amount (i.e. `1 ETH`) as the channel balance ? ex. in `constructor` we **only** initiate `sender`,`recipient` address and `expiry` date. Thx

Comment: The amount to be escrowed is attached when the contract is deployed. (The constructor is `payable`.)

Comment: @smarx Thank you again, but I am really confused at this point. How we attach ex. `1 ETH` at time of deploying the contract ? Thanks

Comment: Are you asking about how to do that in a particular tool or library? If so, which one?

Comment: @smarx Consider for example I want to deploy this contract such that the **total** channel balance is `1 ETH`. I deploy the contract using `web3.js`. Thanks

Comment: In web3.js 0.2x.x: `PaymentChannelContract.new({ ..., value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether') });`.

Comment: @smarx Thanks, And it's not possible to add another parameter to constructor `function SimplePaymentChannel(address _recipient, uint256 duration)` as `function SimplePaymentChannel(address _recipient, uint256 duration, uint256 _channelBalance)` ? Thanks

Comment: What would that parameter do? The contract only has as much ether in it as you send to it.

Comment: @smarx Thanks, OK. I try to do. It's my first time to deploy a contract with constructor that has parameters. Hope I can do it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79644/discussion-on-question-by-sas-micro-payment-channel-on-ethereum).

Answer (score 1):

Connext is working on this exact use case, code examples are below. They have built multi-hop channels using a hub and are integrating with SpankChain currently:

https://github.com/ConnextProject

Please reach out if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

There is working example ( It's being used on Ropsten testnet only ) - https://github.com/orinocopay/orinoco/wiki